# Rails method being called multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im logging certain calls to the show method in various controllers. The idea is to have a table with all the requests to certain models. To have all the logs in a same table a used a polymorfic association. The Basic idea is the following(extended to various models, Images, Sounds, Videos).

**videos_controller.rb**

```
def show 
   @video.create_log_entry(@video.id, 'Video', DateTime.now)
end
```

For the image and sound models it works perfectly, but for the videos show action it creates two corresponding logs. My intuition is that rails is calling the show method twice.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. This probably isn't enough code for us to figure out what's going on... perhaps show us the detail of this create_log_entry method and look for any other instances of it... also where/when is show getting called? (show us the code, don't just tell us). Thirdly, can you look in your server logs (eg `log/development.log` or in your console window) and show us the logs from when you call the show-action? (and a few lines on either side)? that'll help us pinpoint what is going on...

Comment: Note: don't post code to the comments (ie a reply to here) edit your question and add the code directly there as this stuff should always be a part of your original question (and code-formatting in comments is dreadful and hard to read)